# Can blender create a topology of a face from real camera? (photogrammetry)

Tags: mesh, objects, camera, tracking

If you record your face on film, then use blender to create a geometry from it with its aligning topology. Is that possible? Using camera tracking? How?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Blender can't do this (easily), but it is possible to do this with OpenSource Photogrammetry software  (PPT and MeshLab) outside of Blender, then import the resulting model, see:

Example, blog posts.

- http://arc-team-open-research.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/converting-pictures-into-3d-mesh-with.html
- http://arc-team-open-research.blogspot.com.au/2013/04/scanning-skulls-to-forensics-with-ppt.html

Tools:

- http://opensourcephotogrammetry.blogspot.com.au
- http://meshlab.sourceforge.net

Blender-Artists Thread (~2012):

- http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?280309-opensource-3D-scaning-with-one-camera-blender-ppt-meshlab

Answer (score 5):

It can be done with blender, but it would be easier with different programs. You could get a close model by placing a LOT of tracking markers, like in [this](http://vimeo.com/87658924) video.

It sounds like [123D Catch](http://www.123dapp.com/catch) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Some friends did that for a project and did it all with freeware...

**Capture**: First you capture your face with a kinect and extract a point cloud of your face (using depth as your parameter). A good idea would be to block any other stuff in the background by using a sheet, just so you get less garbage points (which need to be cleaned up).

**Clean-up**: The cleaning up could be done with a very short script that deletes all points a certain radius from the "origin" of your face, or if you want to be more clever, you can derive an algorithm that deletes points based on their closest neighbours... in such a way you will keep only the bulk of points which form your face and delete the garbage once scattered around... (in theory)

**Reconstruct surface**: there are many algorithms, techniques and programs, which would reconstruct a point cloud. I would suggest having a look at the following [blender skinning script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pointcloudskin/) or [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) which specializes in such stuff.

Result would depend on the density of the point cloud and the quality of the reconstruction, but you can get a decent result. They got an animation of a human face, but I must warn you, you will be dealing with big data.