# 2d image to a 3d model

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, image, 3d-printing

Anyone know any add ons or anything that is robust enough to turn a full body 2d image of a person into a 3d model?  If something like that even exists.

For an example if I took a full body picture of myself and put it into the software to convert it into a full 3d obj model.

This link is a good example of what I'm trying to accomplish. But a full body obj instead of just the head

https://youtu.be/geQCzan6Usc

Is this possible to do within blender or by any other means?

Comment: Never heard of anything like it for Blender. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63246/how-do-i-make-a-3-dimensional-character-out-of-flat-picture

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41813/how-to-do-photogrammetry-within-blender/42188#42188

Answer (score 4):

What you are referring to is called [Photogrammetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_photogrammetry_software), another option could be a [3D scanner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_scanner)

At this stage there aren't any options available in blender and I don't know of any addons. What is currently available is standalone software that creates a 3d model from an image. Some of the available options listed in the above link might be used to get a 3d model that you could then import into blender.

Normally blender users use images as a reference when modeling or sculpting within blender. An image can be shown in the 3DView as a [background](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/background_images.html) image or attached to an [empty](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/empties.html).

Answer (score 2):

A while ago I followed this guide to do exactly what you want: http://wedidstuff.heavyimage.com/index.php/2013/07/12/open-source-photogrammetry-workflow/

Problems you can get into with this:

- The free software to perform the photogrammetry does not allow for commercial use.
- The free software to perform the photogrammetry is VERY (note: VERY) difficult to install.
- You need to have some command line knowledge and be prepared to fail a few times.
- You need at least 50 pictures of the object (In this case the person) in the same exact perfect position without moving an inch. Which for a human is difficult to say the least.

But beyond those points, it's totally doable, in fact there's a multi-camera setup that allows to do this in just one picture, since it has all 50 cameras pointing in all the different needed angles at once.

Please note that there's proprietary software that also allows to do this, but depending on what you need it for, you will have to pay for it. All that is explained in the article I linked.

Hope it helps!

Edit1: The output of this method is more or less useful depending on what you need it for. If you needed to rig and animate the person, then you would have to re-mesh the whole thing.I would strongly suggest to take the time to model the whole person by following a top, side and front views by hand, since it will be similarly as time consuming and give you better output (and experience) :D