# How can I model from angeled photos in blender?

Tags: modeling

I know that in blender you can use blueprints to model any vehicle but I couldn't found any blueprints for this bus VDL Jonkheere Mistral 30 from the Jutc company and I would love to start a project for it. I also tried writing a letter to the manufacturers asking permission for blueprints and didn't get a response. However I do have alot of images of the bus as I am from Jamaica but I'm not sure if the images needs to be flat like how a typical blueprint would look like (Front view, side view etc). I need professional advice thanks.

[image]

Comment: Appreciative but what about lens distortion how can I correct it? cause that can make the photo look more rounded that it actually is and also does the quality of the photo matter I don't have a Iphone but rather an Andriod phone.

Comment: phone camera will do fine. If you have multiple images the distortion does not matter, every photogrammetry software can account for it. You can do a 3D scan or you can track markers from the photographs inside Blender using camera mapping/tracking - then you get the markers in 3d space perfectly placed. Modeling from blueprints is old-fascioned and usually flawed, because they do not line up propertly and don't contain enough details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [blam](https://github.com/stuffmatic/blam) (or [fSpy](https://fspy.io/)) to match the camera with the a photo and model from there. See this link that outlines the way to do it: [How can I recreate the floor using a photograph?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102697/how-can-i-recreate-the-floor-using-a-photograph/102750#102750)

If you have access to a bus that is parked and you can do the photographs yourself it would be a lot easier. Just go around the bus making a lot of photos with the same lens, import the images into the video clip editor and then use motion tracking as an aid to re-construct the object.

Read: [How to do photogrammetry within Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41813/how-to-do-photogrammetry-within-blender/42188#42188)

You don't need a fancy camera. A phone will be good enough. If you are concerned about the distortion of the lens, Blender has tools to undistort the image.

Read: [How to determine lens undistortion values for motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/how-to-determine-lens-undistortion-values-for-motion-tracking/15622#15622)

Comment: good, any tips for modeling the interior and also the bottom area of the bus?