# Workflow for using A LOT of reference images at precise angles?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, image, sculpting, photogrammetry

I am going to sculpt a human head based on a model whose image is captured at VERY precise angles for this purpose. I think the angles those images are taken at are increments of 11.25 degrees:

{-45.0,-33.75,-22.5,-11.25,0.0,11.25,22.5,33.75,45.0}

[image]

The picture almost speaks for itself: I want to set up each of these references on its own plane, and make it ONLY visible when viewed at the angle it was taken from; this way, I only have to press the `0`-key to look through the camera and pivot around the origin with the `4` and `5`-keys. I can do this, but I don't know how to show just one reference based on the camera angle.

However, **I am also wondering if this is a wild goose chase**: would the depth distortion caused by viewing the reference image in Perspective mode, or the sculpting object in Orthographic mode, make sculpting from the extra angles impossible to replicate the human model correctly? Are only orthogonal reference angles (i.e. front, side, back, top, etc) useful for manual photogrammetry?

(I looked at all the top Suggestions while writing this question, none of them asked about implementing this same feature. If I missed an existing solution, please link me to it if it will work for 2.81)

**EDIT:** Ok, forget about making all those reference images because I'm going to just slice the images I have and feed them to Facebuilder (which I think uses perspective cameras?). But I do want to know if that approach was feasible without that software or if the distortion would make it an impossible task.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110532/cannot-find-background-images-feature-in-blender-2-8

Comment: You can try using motion tracking and reconstructing the geometry based the image sequence like in this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41813/how-to-do-photogrammetry-within-blender/42188#42188

Comment: It is quite unfortunate that the chosen background is black so tracking the hair will not be as easy.  Also to compensate for the lens distortion you can undistort the images see:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/how-to-determine-lens-undistortion-values-for-motion-tracking/15622#15622

Comment: check out http://insight3d.sourceforge.net/ and http://www.meshlab.net/#features

Comment: Think I'm going to use Facebuilder after all

Comment: http://www.regard3d.org/index.php/documentation/tutorial and https://alicevision.org/#meshroom